# PHP DOMDocument missing

Tags: php, domdocument, require

I am getting an odd error when running $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");:
**Warning**:  require_once(classes/DOMDocument.class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/var/www/html/cms/bootstrap.php** on line **5**

**Fatal error**:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'classes/DOMDocument.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/cms/plugins/Zend/library') in **/var/www/html/cms/bootstrap.php** on line **5**

According to php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php, I need php-xml installed. I have tried this but it also errors out...

```
[user@lnxcmsdev cms]$ sudo yum install php-xml
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.web-ster.com
 * base: mirror.hmc.edu
 * extras: mirror.hmc.edu
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: mirror.rocketinternet.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xml.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-xml
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-xml-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-xml-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-xml-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
[user@lnxcmsdev cms]$ sudo yum install php-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.web-ster.com
 * base: mirror.hmc.edu
 * extras: mirror.hmc.edu
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: mirror.rocketinternet.net
Setting up Install Process
Package matching php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

Ideas??

Comment: Here's the DOM requirments - http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.requirements.php. Also, PHP 5.1.6 is pretty old now. You should consider upgrading

Comment: Your problem is the package manager, not PHP. Download the RPM manually and use `rpm --nodeps --force php-xml*.rpm` to install it.

Comment: [user@lnxcmsdev cm]$ sudo yum --enablerepo=webtatic install libxml
Setting up Install Process
No package libxml available.
Nothing to do

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-xml
sudo /sbin/service httpd stop
sudo /sbin/service httpd start
```

Answer (score 1):

First Install this rpm

rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

Then install

sudo yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-xml

This should 100% works.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, I have php71 REMI installed on Centos7.

I checked this:

```
yum install php-xml
```

But It was installed and I got this message:

```
Package php-xml-7.1.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Then I tried this one:

```
yum install php71-php-xml
```

And It was missed, So I got

```
Dependencies Resolved

=====================================
 Package                    Arch                Version                        Repository         Size
=====================================
Installing:
 php71-php-xml              x86_64              7.1.4-1.el7.remi               remi              164 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================
Install  1 Package
```

I answered yes and It installed.
Then restart the httpd2.4:

```
service httpd restart
```

Then the problem was fixed.